# How to bind Command to Check Box in ListView WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, icommand, relaycommand

### Update

I edited the code below to match the suggestions and it works correctly now.

I've seen several stack overflow questions similar to this one, but I haven't quite been able to put it all together.  I have the following xaml code.

```
<UserControl x:Class="AuditEfficiencyMVVM.View.AuditTestsMain"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:AuditEfficiencyMVVM.View"
         xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:AuditEfficiencyMVVM.ViewModel"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="500" d:DesignWidth="1000">

<UserControl.DataContext>
    <viewmodel:AuditTests/>
</UserControl.DataContext>

<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <ListView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Margin="10" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Tests}">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <CheckBox Name="TestSelected" IsChecked="{Binding Path=Selected, Mode=TwoWay}" Command="{Binding Path=TestSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Test Type" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Type, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Progress">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ProgressBar Name="TestProgress" Width="50" Height="20" Value="{Binding Progress, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Status" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Status, Mode=OneWay}"/>                    
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>

        <ListView.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate>
                                    <Expander IsExpanded="True">
                                        <Expander.Header>
                                            <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="14" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                                        </Expander.Header>
                                        <ItemsPresenter/>
                                    </Expander>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
            </GroupStyle>
        </ListView.GroupStyle>
    </ListView>

    <ListView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Margin="10" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Files}">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="File Type" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Type, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="File Location" Width="250">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Location, Mode=TwoWay}" Width="225"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>                    
                <GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Button Width="30" Height="20">...</Button>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>

    <Button Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="10" Width="50" Height="30">Run</Button>
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Here is my code behind

```
public class AuditTests : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private RelayCommand _testSelected;

    private void AddTest()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Success");
    }

    public RelayCommand TestSelected
    {
        get
        {
            return _testSelected;
        }
        private set
        {
            if (_testSelected != value)
            {
                _testSelected = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("TestSelected");
            }                
        }
    }

    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        }
    }

    public AuditTests()
    {
        TestSelected = new RelayCommand(AddTest);
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Model.File> Files
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Model.Test> Tests
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public void LoadFiles()
    {
        ObservableCollection<Model.File> files = new ObservableCollection<Model.File>();

        foreach (Model.Test test in Tests)
        {
            foreach (Enums.FileType type in test.ExpectedSources)
            {
                Boolean containsType = false;
                foreach (Model.File file in files)
                {
                    if (file.Type == type)
                    {
                        containsType = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (!containsType)
                {
                    files.Add(new Model.File { Type = type, Location = "", Tests = new List<Enums.TestType> { test.Type } });
                }
                else
                {
                    files.Where(t => t.Type == type).First().Tests.Add(test.Type);
                }
            }
        }

        Files = files;
    }

    public void LoadTests()
    {
        ObservableCollection<Model.Test> tests = new ObservableCollection<Model.Test>();

        foreach (var prop in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Enums.TestType)).Cast<Enums.TestType>().ToList())
        {
            tests.Add(new Model.Test { Category = prop.GetCategory(), Type = prop, Progress = 0, Selected = true, Status = Enums.TestStatus.NotStarted, ExpectedSources = prop.GetExpectedFiles() });
        }

        Tests = tests;
    }        
}
}
```

From what I've read this seems like it should work, but when I check/uncheck the check box the message box is not activated.  What am I missing here to get the check/uncheck command to work?

Comment: That's not a codebehind, that's a model or something. How do you connect the `AuditTests` class with the `AuditTestsMain` UserControl?

Comment: @EdPlunkett I guess I don't now that I look at it.  I connect the List Views to the Observable Collections, but it doesn't look like I connect the view as a whole to the `AuditTests`.  Would that be a DataContext thing?

Comment: Yes. It looks to me like `AuditTests` wants to be a viewmodel. It should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, and when you use your UserControl, it should have an instance of `AuditTests` for its DataContext. This is in addition to what ASh points out below.

Comment: @EdPlunkett How would I set the Data Context Correctly?  I've got `DataContext = "{}"` in the `<UserControl>`, but I'm not sure how to specify the file.  `AuditTestsMain.xaml` is in View/ while `AuditTests.cs` is in ViewModel/

Comment: That's going to depend on who's responsible for creating `AuditTests`. It doesn't matter what folders the classes are defined in. How are you using `AuditTestsMain`? Do you just want to toss an instance of it in anywhere and have it do its thing? Or does some other viewmodel own a copy of `AuditTests`, and it wants to display that in its own view?

Comment: @EdPlunkett `AuditTestsMain` will be set in `MainWindow.xaml` which is the only place it will be used.  `MainWindow` may replace `AuditTestsMain` with other content in the future, but right now it's just the one user control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I'd make `AuditTests` implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, and raise `PropertyChanged` in all its property setters when their values change. There's a lot of documentation out there on doing that.

Second, you've got to give the user control a copy of it. I can't tell if you gave your UserControl any properties of its own that MainWindow may want to put bindings on; if that's the case, it's a more complicated question. But the simplest thing is this:

```
public AuditTestsMain()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    //  Now its parent view can't bind this guy's properties to properties of the 
    //  parent's view's viewmodel, because we've broken DataContext inheritance. 
    DataContext = new ViewModels.AuditTests();
}
```

Then look at ASh's answer for how to bind the command. That's another DataContext thing: The thing there is that the listview items are `Model.Test` instances. So inside that `DataTemplate` for the items, bindings bind to the properties of `Model.Test` by default, because that's the `DataContext`. But the command is not a property of `Model.Test`; it's a property of `AuditTests`. `AuditTests` is the UserControl's DataContext, and therefore it's the ListView's DataContext as well. Controls inherit the parent's DataContext unless something interferes with that -- like the line I'm adding to your `AuditTestsMain` constructor, or like the way the ListView creates child items which have the listview's items as their DataContext.

Answer (score 2):

`TestSelected` command is a property `AuditTests` object. DataContext of CheckBox is Model.Test object. They are on different levels. You can bind command to a property from ListView DataContext with `RelativeSource` parameter:

```
Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.TestSelected, 
                  RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}}"
```